# EXTJS RestFul Grid + Form Using same RestFul interface

Tags: extjs, extjs3

My grid utilises the restful:true parameter

When you click on a grid row - it maps the row values to a form.
The form contains a submit button

At the moment I am utilising the standard AJAX

However what I want to do is utilise the Grids own Rest service that I have already implemented. The below does not actually give me the exact results.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url : '/service/' + Ext.getCmp('id').getValue(),
    method  : 'PUT',
    headers : {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    },
    params  : Ext.util.JSON.encode({'data' : gridForm.form.getValues()}),
    success : function (result, request)
    {
        store.reload();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the encode statement, you don't have to do so.

```
params  : {'data' : gridForm.form.getValues()},
```